# PHP Dividing a string into parts

Tags: php, regex, string, explode

I have a string $str which holds the below information

> Cricket Batting:India Score:99/2 Date:27 June 2013

I want break this string into 4 parts and that should be like this:

```
$part1 = "Cricket";
$part2 = "Batting:India";
$part3 = "Score:99/2";
$part4 = "Date:27 June 2013";
```

I tried using explode() but the problem is values doesn't stand same always. For example it could be:

```
Cricket Batting:South Africa Score:203/10 Date:7 May 2013
or this:
Cricket Batting:Australia Score:1/1 Date:27 September 2019
```

So, when I use explode South and africa will split into different variables. I can't use  wordwrap()  as length of the string varies from time to time.

Comment: Why do you have it in that string instead of separate fields in the first place?

Comment: @Nile Actually, When I parsed a xml file, I got this html content with links,images etc. I, then, removed them using strip_tags() and stored it in the $str variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use *preg_split* with this pattern:

```
~ (?=Batting|Score|Date)~
```

Comment: Heh, and I was writing a *matching* pattern. +1

Comment: Thanks guys, but a matching pattern is possible too.

Answer (score 3):

The **[preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)** function is the best solution in this case:

```
preg_split('/\s(?=\w+:)/ ', $str);
```

Splitting point explained below:

`\s` - matches one space

`(?=\w+:)` - positive lookahead matching a word followed by a colon

Comment: +1 Good idea, but keep in mind that this pattern requires more testing (until the `:` is found)